# VBA: How to delete Column "A" in a specific Folder with different files with Sheet name that varies

Tags: vba, excel, csv, macros

I have a folder in my Desktop with more or less 2000 `csv` files. Those files have only 1 "Sheet" but the sheet name varies. The only similar thing is that it starts with the word "Tankard".

In that one sheet, I just need to remove `Column A` and Save it, for all 2000 files. Its only my 2nd month to explore vba automation at work. I'd appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Script:

```
Sub Tank()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myfile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim SheetName As String
'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

SheetName = "Tankard*"
  myPath = "\\ph00winfdfs01p\shares\JoeyC\documents\Roaming\Windows\Desktop\Tank\"
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "Tankard*.csv"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myfile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
For i = 1 To 201
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myfile)
';;;;;;;;;;;;;;WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
Sheets("SheetName").Select
Columns("A").Select
Selection.Delete
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

Next i
'Get next file name
myfile = Dir

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't the sheet name just be the file name (without extension) when opening a csv file? (I have no experience with csv files and excel but that's what it just did for me)

Comment: Thanks for your input. My problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand what's happening. What this sub does at the moment is opening the first workbook that `Dir` can find, opening it 201 times and deleting the first column of sheet "Sheetname" every time.

```
Sheets("SheetName").Select
```

This selects the sheet with the name `"Sheetname"`, not the name with the value that you set the string `Sheetname` to. If anything, it should be `Sheets(Sheetname)` but wildcards don't work here anyways.

Now let's look at the process you're trying to achieve.

```
myfile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
```

sets `myfile` to the first file that matches your pattern `...\Tankard*.csv`

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myfile)
```

opens the file and now you can access the workbook via `wb`

To delete the first column on the sheet I would recommend selecting all that stuff but deleting the range directly:

```
wb.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Delete 'If you want to actually delete the column
wb.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Clear  'If you want to just remove the values
```

As you can see you don't need the name of the sheet at all. Now save the workbook:

```
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Now you can set `myfile` to the next filename using `Dir`:

```
myfile = Dir
```

Then repeat that until there are no more files (at that point `Dir` will return `""`. The best way to achieve that is to use a `While` loop, e.g. like this

```
While myfile <> ""
    'Do stuff here
Wend '(While End)
```

The advantage over a `For` loop is that you don't need to know the exact number of files in your folder.

I'll leave it up to you to patch that all together.

Comment: i was able to put all your suggestions together. It worked! thanks. New to vba, just trying to understand the concepts through this site and other sites. Plus youtube videos. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help. You might consider marking this as answered then ;)